# Switched from Heroku to Scaleway and server is much slower

Tags: docker, performance

I recently moved our backend services from Heroku (hobby-Tier (8€/month)) to Scaleway (DEV-L, 20€/month) as well as the database (similar prices).
We did this because of all the issues with the privacy shield and data security.

For this, we needed to containerize the application and I added some additional stuff (Grafana/Prometheus and Elastic Stack).

The problem is, that the server is much slower now. I mean A LOT. Before we had for very complex and large queries loading times of about 3-5 seconds, now sometimes like 20 to 25.

Do you have any idea what the problem could be? Or are the 'dynos' on Heroku just very optimized?
I tried shutting down all containers which aren't needed (only Nginx, certbot, and the actual backend left) but that didn't help. I also tried to upgrade the server or the database, which of course improved the performance, but only so little (max 20% for 150€) for so much money.

Additionally Grafana tells me that the server isn't even used to capacity. Generally, the cpu usage is around 50% (most of the time) to max 125%, the backend itself never above 60 % (if there is a 'complex' request).

```
###
# BUIDLER
###
FROM python:3.6.12-alpine3.12 as builder

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN apk update \
    && apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev \
    ca-certificates gcc postgresql-dev linux-headers \
    libffi-dev jpeg-dev zlib-dev
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY . .
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip wheel --no-cache-dir --no-deps --wheel-dir /usr/src/app/wheels -r requirements.txt




#########
# FINAL #
#########

# pull official base image
FROM python:3.6.12-alpine3.12

# create directory for the app user
RUN mkdir -p /home/app

# create the app user
RUN addgroup -S app && adduser -S app -G app

# create the appropriate directories
ENV HOME=/home/app
ENV APP_HOME=/home/app/web
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

# install dependencies
RUN apk update && apk add libpq postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev

COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/wheels /wheels
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache /wheels/*

# copy project
COPY . $APP_HOME

# chown all the files to the app user
RUN chown -R app:app $APP_HOME

# change to the app user
USER app
```

Comment: Are you sure no modifications were made when containerizing the application? This sounds more like a database index issue than a server issue.

Comment: To be honest I'm no expert with Docker and especially dockerized Django applications. There should be no code differences. I added my Dockerfile.
I took the configuration mostly from this tutorial: https://testdriven.io/blog/dockerizing-django-with-postgres-gunicorn-and-nginx/